# Nginx an Error Occured on Ubuntu Server 13.1

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, flask, uwsgi, ubuntu-server

Hi I am currently trying to setup a restful api using Flask on a Ubuntu 13.1 server which i am accessing via ssh. I thought I had correctly setup nginx and uwsgi, however when I navigate to my IP address in a browser (xxx.xxx.x.xxx) I get the following message instead of the classic nginx welcome page:

"An error occurred. Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable.
Please try again later. If you are the system administrator of this resource then you should check the error log for details."

When I checked the nginx error logs here's what I saw:

```
2014/03/22 08:51:12 [crit] 23903#0: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.x.2xx, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock:", host: "xxx.xxx.x.1xx"
```

The tutorial I followed is here: http://conra.dk/2012/05/06/flask-uwsgi-nginx-ubuntu.html

Here are my files:

**/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx-lucid.list :**

```
deb http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ lucid nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ lucid nginx
```

**/etc/init/uwsgi.conf**

```
description "uWSGI"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel[06]

respawn

exec uwsgi --master --processes 4 --die-on-term --uid uwsgi --gid nginx --socket /tmp/uwsgi.sock --chmod-socket 660 --no-site --vhost --logto /var/log/uwsgi.log
```

**/etc/logrotate.d/uwsgi**

```
/var/log/uwsgi.log {
    rotate 10
    daily
    compress
    missingok
    create 640 uwsgi adm
    postrotate
        initctl restart uwsgi >/dev/null 2>&1
    endscript
}
```

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/helloworld.conf**

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /static {
        alias /srv/www/helloworld/static;
    }

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_PYHOME /srv/www/helloworld/env;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_CHDIR /srv/www/helloworld;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_MODULE application;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_CALLABLE app;
    }

    error_page   404              /404.html;

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

so when i restart uwsgi using:

```
sudo service uwsgi restart
```

I get this message:

```
stop: Unknown instance: 
uwsgi start/running, process 23969
```

Then when I try and run

```
uwsgi --http 127.0.0.1:9090 --pyhome ./env --module application --callable app
```

I get this message:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.3 (64bit) on [Sat Mar 22 09:31:52 2014] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.1 on 22 March 2014 08:00:25
os: Linux-3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 9 16:20:46 UTC 2013
nodename: upsilon
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 8
current working directory: /srv/www/helloworld
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 31452
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uWSGI http bound on 127.0.0.1:9090 fd 4
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 23989)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:39396 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
Python version: 2.7.5+ (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:40:54)  [GCC 4.8.1]
Set PythonHome to ./env
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x2667f70
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 72752 bytes (71 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./application.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named flask
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 23988, cores: 1)
```

Comment: `ImportError: No module named flask` seems to be the main error-- so you're not activating your virtualenv correctly, or haven't installed Flask to that venv.